# Playing video as Splash Screen in Android using Xamarin

Tags: android, video, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I am trying to play a video as a Splash Screen in Android using `Xamarin`. I found the link below but I am getting `file not found exception`. I tried passing the path a few different ways but haven't had any success.

My video `Splash.mp4` is in drawable folder inside Resources and `SplashActivity.cs` file is at project level.

[play video in Android using Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466191/play-video-in-android-using-xamarin)

```
 [Activity(Label = "SplashVideo", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashVideo : Activity, MediaPlayer.IOnPreparedListener, ISurfaceHolderCallback
{
    VideoView videoView;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.VideoLayout);
        videoView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.SampleVideoView);

        play();
    }
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    void play()
    {
        ISurfaceHolder holder = videoView.Holder;
        holder.SetType(SurfaceType.PushBuffers);
        holder.AddCallback(this);

        Android.Content.Res.AssetFileDescriptor afd = Resources.Assets.OpenFd("Splash.mp4");
        if (afd != null)
        {
            player.SetDataSource(afd.FileDescriptor, afd.StartOffset, afd.Length);
            player.Prepare();
            player.Start();
        }
    }

    public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SurfaceCreated");
        player.SetDisplay(holder);
    }

    public void SurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SurfaceDestroyed");
        player.SetDisplay(null);
    }

    public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, Android.Graphics.Format format, int w, int h)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SurfaceChanged");
    }

    public void OnPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your code, not a link to another person's code. This will help to better understand what you may have done incorrectly.

Comment: At least show us how you tell Xamarin where the file location is... That could be a fast way to spot what's causing "file not found" issue.

Comment: Added my code. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @user3660264
Can you please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Video has to be in the assets folder, not drawable